# How to put the edited date of a cell into another cell in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets, is there a simpler way to put the edited date of a cell into another cell?

I've set a data validation list:

- ACTIVE
- COMPLETED
- ONHOLD
- TESTING
- BUGFIXING

to F column. If the value of F column is changed to ACTIVE, the value of corresponding G column cell should be that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following little script you can do that.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range, c = r.getColumn(), v = e.value;
  if(v == "ACTIVE" && c == 6) {
    r.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date);    
  }
}
```

### Explained

The `onEdit` trigger is only fired if column F is selected (`c == 6`) and if the value of the list is (changed to) `ACTIVE` (`v == "ACTIVE"`). After that it will change the range one column length (`r.offset(0, 1)`) and add the date.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Add date to adjoining column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G-Sk9bhKuH4GmeSwQhz_AAE0ivtGD-NFiqeXJkz4HRw/edit?usp=sharing)**
Add the script via *Tools > Script editor*, press the save button and you're on the go.

Comment: It worked, How to set the value in previous column's cell

Comment: @tvshajeer Then use this instead: `r.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date);`